# For protobuf-net, are there any circumstances under which DeserializeWithLengthPrefix<T> can throw an exception?

Tags: c#, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net

I am making an app with protobuf-net, using it for sending/receiving data over the network.

I am curious whether/how someone can send something that will make this line throw an exception:

```
var message = Serializer.DeserializeWithLengthPrefix<ReceiveType>(
                                   memoryStream, PrefixStyle.Fixed32);
```

I am assuming that by this point we've checked that:

- (Edit) Entire message has already been received and was placed into a [`MemoryStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.aspx), which will be used for deserializing the message (i.e. no risk of the stream cutting off).
- The length prefix contains a number of reasonable size (i.e. won't run out of memory)
- Message body is exactly as large as promised by the prefix.

So far I've tried various possibilities, and at worst the `message` fields come out to be `null` or other default values, even for the required fields and when the message body contains random gibberish.

Comment: By coincidence, I was messing around with protobuf-net last night for a couple hours, and I found that if you try to use `Serializer.DeserializeWithLengthPrefix<T>()` on a stream that has been closed, the `Serializer.DeserializeWithLengthPrefix<T>()` line will throw an error at runtime.

Comment: Interesting, thanks!  I forgot to mention though that before deserializing, I wait for the entire message to arrive (based on length prefix) and then deserialize from a `MemoryStream`, i.e. there is no risk of stream being closed.  I'll edit the post to clarify.

Comment: @BrianSnow were you getting an exception or an error. Because attempts with Sockets to operate on a closed stream throw exceptions which you need to catch, so i'd say mark would follow those pretty closely.

Comment: @PaulFarry  It was an exception, which I did catch.  I am a newbie, and I actually didn't know that exceptions and errors are two different things!

Comment: Too late to edit my comment above, but just to be sure: if I was catching the error/exception with `catch (Exception e) {}`, am I correct in assuming that means it was indeed an exception?

Comment: indeed, if you were catching it (Im guessing `IOException` then yeah you've got it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> and when the message body contains random gibberish

not quite. Gibberish will *generally* make it throw the "invalid wire type" exception. You could also get errors about malformed varints, UTF8, and several other things. The message *must* be valid protobuf data.There are some things it won't detect, but in most cases it will shout at you for invalid data.

Obviously any code in `ReceiveType` that intentionally explodes (in say, a property get) would cause it to fail - so the model / DTO must make sense too!